How do I put an image on top of another using TailwindCSS?
I'm trying to put one image on top of another on my InfoComponent, and I want it to look something like this:

However, I just can't seem to do it. I need to make it responsive. I have no idea how to make it a one-size-fits-all type scenario, so it just looks like this:

Here's my code:
<div class="flex items-center justify-center">
  <!--Card-->
  <div
    class="bg-blue-500 mt-12 mx-6 lg:w-[100vh] md:w-[75vh] md:h-[30vh] md:mb-4 rounded-2xl"
  >
    <!-- Flex Container -->
    <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row rounded-l-xl h-full">
      <!-- Image -->
      <img
        src="implementations.jpeg"
        alt=""
        class="relative object-fit rounded-t-xl h-80 md:w-[31vh] lg:w-[37vh] md:h-full md:rounded-l-xl md:rounded-tr-none opacity-40"
      />
      <img
        src="overlay1.png"
        class="absolute object-fit rounded-t-xl w-[20vh] md:rounded-l-xl md:rounded-tr-none bottom-[-35vh]  md:bottom-[-35vh] lg:bottom-[26vh] xl:bottom-[15vh] left-[25vh] md:ml-14 lg:ml-24"
      />

      <!--Content-->
      <div class="p-6 md:px-8 lg:px-12 lg:mt-3 sh:p-2 sh:px-6">
        <h2
          class="text-xl md:text-2xl lg:text-3xl sh:text-xl font-bold text-center text-white md:text-left"
        >
          Implementations
        </h2>

        <p
          class="max-w-4xl md:max-w-2xl my-4 lg:my-0 lg:mt-4 md:mt-4 sh:mt-2 text-md md:text-md sh:text-sm lg:text-xl leading-5 tracking-wide text-center text-white md:text-left"
        >
          Whether it’s adding a new module to your existing Oracle PeopleSoft
          application or replacing a legacy ERP, we will perform fit-gap
          analysis, write data conversion processes and any other activities you
          need to ensure a successful project.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

I've tried putting the two images into divs, but that would mess up the width of the first image on smaller screens. I've used different classes, like absolute and relative, used top-0, left-0, etc. How can I get this to work?

Is this what you want?

You could either:
a) use the “background-image” CSS property to set one image as the background.
b) make your outer div “position: relative” and then set both your images to “position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50; transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
The above is just base CSS rules, but you should be able to find the corresponding Tailwind classes through a quick web search.
